# Multiple credit risk mitigation (CRM) treatment in RWA calculation in F-IRB approach Basel II

Tags: credit-risk, basel

I have a confusion about how to calculate RWA for a exposure with many types of CRM (says, collaterals and guarantee) in IRB approach.

- In BCBS128, point 206, "In the case where a bank has multiple CRM techniques covering a single exposure (e.g. a bank has both collateral and guarantee partially covering an exposure), the bank will be required to **subdivide the exposure into portions covered by each type of CRM technique** (e.g. portion covered by collateral, portion covered by guarantee) and the risk-weighted assets of each portion must be calculated separately"
  But this is for SA approach, I'm not sure if this rule is valid for F-IRB approach. If If you divide the exposure into portions, will the collateral or guarantee be recognized first?
  Please look at the below example:
- A senior loan with exposure of 100k USD,
- CRE/RRE collateral covers 30k USD. LGD applied for CRE/RRE is 0.35 according to bcbs128.
- Guarantee covers 20k USD.
- The rest (no collateralized, no guaranteed): 20k USD.
- The LGD applied for no collateralized part is 0.45 (according to bcbs128)
- PD of the customer is 5%, PD of the guarantor is 2%

As far as we understand, the LGD can be calculated as below. **Please confirm if we understand correctly.**

- The collateralized part (30k) will be applied the LGD of 0.35, PD = 5%
- The guaranteed part (20k) will be applied LGD of 0.45, PD = 2%
- The no guaranteed/collateralized part (50k) will be both applied the LGD of 0.45, PD = 5%

If Guarantee in above example covers 80k (instead of 20k), collateral covers 30k, how should we divide exposure 100k?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use the more favorable CRM, in this case the guarantee with the 80k and for the rest you take the CRE/RRE CRM. Y don't need to use the full available RRE/CRE. IMHO you do some allocation the most risky exposure get the most favorable CRM to reduce the RWA